# ¿Como hago para afectar la orientación de los elementos de acuerdo al cambio de columna, si es xs-sm entre otras?

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo definidas las columnas y además ahí mismo vinculé una clase para que el texto y elementos queden orientados a la derecha. Sin embargo la inquietud que planteo es de **col-lg** para arriba deseo que el texto y elementos estén orientados a la derecha, pero de **col-md** para abajo deseo que el texto quede orientado de manera central ¿Como hago?

¿Como hago para afectar la orientación de los elementos de acuerdo al cambio de columna, si es xs-sm entre otras?

```html
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-right">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
            <div class="redes-footer">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-12 text-right">
    <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
    <div class="redes-footer">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

- `col-xs` aplicara cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea inferior a 768px
- `col-sm` aplicara cuando el ancho de la pantalla este comprendido entre 768px y 992px
- `col-md` aplicara cuando el ancho de la pantalla este comprendido entre 992px y 1200px
- `col-lg` aplicara cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea mayor a 1200px

Siguiendo esa lógica, si quieres que a partir de `col-md` sea centrado, bastaría con asignar 6 columnas para `md` y un `offset` de 3 por cada lado, de tal manera la columna estaría alineada en el centro y aplicando un `col-lg-12` y el `text-right`, la columna ocuparía todo el ancho y alinearía el texto a la derecha.

Answer (score 2):

Esta es mi solución, usa `@media` que nos brinda `css` para ajustar atributos `css` en diferentes tamaños, lo que hice fue que cuando el contenido sea mayor de `1200px` coloque el texto a la derecha, y que cuando el texto sea menor de `1199px` coloque el texto centrado, puedes jugar con esas dimensiones y ajustar un ancho como tu desees, si quieres que el texto sea centrado para tu clase `col-md` entonces colocas `@media (max-width: 992px)`, es tu decisión ya mirar como lo colocas. Saludos.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .custom-text {
    text-align: right;
  }  
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .custom-text {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 custom-text col-lg-12">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
            <div class="redes-footer">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Saludos, muchas gracias, me ha servido tu aporte, gracias.